# Is Liquid Air Safe?

Tags: liquids, oxygen, nitrogen

Does Liquid Air mitigate the asphyxiation risks associated with Liquid Nitrogen?
As Oxygen and Nitrogen have marginally different boiling points, do you run the risk of all the nitrogen boiling off first, leaving behind a very flammable, very dangerous pure liquid Oxygen? Assuming you were to store the liquid air in a dewar tank, approximately how long would it take for this to become a concern, if at all?

Comment: Effective ventilation reduces the risk. Why would liquid air be better than that?

Comment: Since they will boil off at different temperatures, no, it just causes other problems.

Comment: Oxygen is flammable only in reducing atmosphere, like H2, CH4 or NH3.

Comment: Well, if you are running pure oxygen in non-rated plumbing it will (un)happily make some exciting flames just fine…

Comment: @JonCuster, what are these other problems? Really I'm trying to understand whether you could safely have a dewar of liquid air in a confined space without suffocating anyone.

Comment: You can have a dewar with LN2 in a confined space without suffocating. Unless you tip it over, or live in there for days. You will get a shortage of oxygen, and too much CO2, in there *without* the dewar even. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The boil-off rate of N2 cannot be predicted without knowing exactly the conditions of this ill-advised experiment. Quality of the dewar, its surface-to-volume ratio, outside temperature,  ...

Comment: @Karl, not really an experiment. I just want to know whether using Liquid Air would be safer than Liquid Nitrogen and what safety consideration I would need to make.

Answer (score 0):

If we agree that asphyxiation is lack of providing cells of the the human organism with oxygen, liquid air ***is not safe*** because of its low temperature. Once the isolating buffer of air ([Leidenfrost effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect)) between the liquid air and the gaseous air is off of the alveoli, the tissue will be frozen (and become brittle)* and blood behind these membranes will freeze, too.  Don't forget blood contains much of water, which expands above and below about $\pu{4 ^\circ{}C}$, too.

At atmospheric pressure, the boiling temperature of nitrogen is about $ \pu{-196 ^\circ{}C}$ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen)), the of oxygen about $\pu{-183 ^\circ{}C}$ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen)).  While you argue about *liquid air*, it actually is a known issue as *potential* danger when handling *liquid nitrogen* as a cryogenic.  The very first example which comes to my mind are the Dewar traps installed to protect oil pumps filled with LN instead of dry ice and iPrOH.  The ones filled with LN are cool enough *to condense* oxygen available in the ambient air.  Because *condensed* oxygen supports combustion so much better than gaseous oxygen diluted in air (which is about 78% nitrogen, and 21% oxygen), you just don't *mindlessly* refill these traps with LN again and again.  It isn't safe to await for the blue color of liquid oxygen as an indicator of a risk (and compared to liquid ozone one may trap behind an ozonolysis, its blue is much fainter), nor to use liquid air as a cryogenic.

Running a Linde machine to harvest nitrogen actually requires a number of steps to filter, wash, dry air to remove e.g., dust, pollen, humidity, $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{N2O}$ *before* air is liquefied; and uses a distillation column to remove oxygen trapped by the process.  Hence you see these machines more likely in locales with both reliable and affordable supply of electricity (for the compressors) and water (for the cooling) to provide you with purified (colorless) LN from the pressurized truck / local tank for your lab can.

* Some lectures display shatter e.g., a flexible rubber tube just cooled in liquid nitrogen with a hammer.  More seriously though, [cryogenic grinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenic_grinding) is technique to eventually amend (heat sensitive) samples of polymers and organic materials to an analysis to lower the rates of chemical reactions e.g., if cells are broken up, or because deep frozen samples tend to be less sticky to the grinder.